# java custom class not serializable

Tags: java, class, serialization, deserialization

I have a custom class (constructor below) that I cannot seem to serialize.

```
public ObjectNode(String name, int crackLevel,ArrayList<ObjectNode> filesOnComputer)
```

Every time I try to serialize an object of this class from an ArrayList of object nodes I get a Class cast exception. ArrayList cannot be cast to ObjectNode

Code- Global Vars:

```
    ArrayList<ObjectNode>a=new ArrayList<ObjectNode>();
File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard/","cheesepuff.txt");
```

Relevant Code:

```
        public void serializeFile()
{       
    a.add(new ObjectNode("Level 1 Waterwall","ww1", 1, 5));
    try { 
        Log.i("AAA","before serialize: "+a.toString());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file); 
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos); 
        oos.writeObject(a); 
        oos.flush(); 
        oos.close(); 
        Log.i("AAA","finished serialize");
        } 
        catch(Exception e) { 
        Log.i("aaa","Exception during serialization: " + e); 
        System.exit(0); 
        } 
}

public void deserializeFile()
{
    try { 
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file); 
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis); 
        ObjectNode obj=(ObjectNode)ois.readObject();
        Log.i("aaa","obj: "+obj.ts());
        //a.add((ObjectNode) ois.readObject()); 
        ois.close(); 
        Log.i("aaa","after serialize: " + a); 
        } 
        catch(Exception e) { 
        Log.i("aaa","Exception during deserialization: " + 
        e); 
        System.exit(0); 
        } 
        }
```

Is my best option to make everything a string in order to serialize that, and then convert the string back to what I actually need after deserialization?

Comment: does your class actually implement Serializable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are serializing `a` which is `ArrayList<ObjectNode>`.

```
oos.writeObject(a);
```

When deserializing, you get back exactly that, but you try to store it as `ObjectNode`

```
ObjectNode obj=(ObjectNode)ois.readObject();
```

You should do

```
ArrayList<ObjectNode> obj = (ArrayList<ObjectNode>)ois.readObject();
```

UPDATE: Or, as PeterLawrey correctly states,

```
List<ObjectNode> obj = (List<ObjectNode>) ois.readObject;
```

(probably then you would have to redefine `a` as `List<ObjectNode>`, but that is another good thing to do).

Comment: Ideally a `List<objectNode>`

Comment: why is using a List<C> better then using an ArrayList<C> in this case?

Comment: If you use the more generic definition (that is, the superclass that defines the methods that you need; ideally an interface), changing the specific implementation will be easier when needed. For instance, if you define `a` as `List<ObjectNode>`, you can define it as a `ArrayList<ObjectNode>` or `Vector<ObjectNode>` (or whatever implementation of `List<E>` you chose) just by changing the line where you are creating the list. In your original code, changing the implementation means changing it everywhere it is used (not to mention other code that may use it).

Comment: It is a very documented `good practice`, if you want to search a more extensive explanation for it.

Answer (score 2):

You are writing an ArrayList, this means you must cast it to an ArrayList (or better, a List) when you read it.